# Moto G Play gets wako. Speaker fault. How to find source of problem?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, lenovo, microphone, speaker, speakerphone

Every 24-48 hours my Moto G Play / Android 6.0.1 gets wako meaning:

- (most often) During call I can't hear the other person and other person can't hear me,
- (rare) Notification sounds are played very quietly (nearly silently) even though sounds volume is set to maximum and other tones (i.e. ringtones) are played correctly.

Things that I'm sure:

- restarting phone *always* solves above problems,
- if phone gets wako, problem always narrows to speaker / microphone; all other functionalities (SMS messaging, emails, Internet browsing, playing games, using apps) works normally,
- these situations happens only on my phone; my wife has exactly the same model with exactly the same Android version and nearly exactly the same applications set and hasn't noticed this behavior so far.

Things that I'm uncertain:

- if I'm not mistaken described problems occurs only if phone isn't used very often -- i.e. if there was 6-8+ hours since last call made or received; if I'm calling often, phone doesn't get wako.

How can I check or what can I do to check, if this is software (Android), network (LTE operator) or hardware (Lenovo) problem? What tests or operations should I perform?

I could say (given that wife's phone has absolutely no problems) that this is certainly hardware problem. But then, restarting phone always solves problem, so this would indicate Android / software problem.

Comment: are you using stock phone and messaging apps or third party? if it is third party, check that they are not optimised for battery saving

Comment: @beeshyams Nope, stock one only.

Comment: I still suspect *doze* playing up ( though it shouldn't happen)- go to battery > battery optimisation> select your phone and messaging and make them *not optimised* - may help . I am suspecting doze because of the regular periodicity you mentioned

Comment: @beeshyams Nope, "Not optimized" since this phone ever got to my dirty hands! :>